# Accessing another machine's htdocs in same network but it returns self htdocs

Tags: php, networking, xampp, localhost, htdocs

I have two notebook running Windows 10 and connected in same wireless network.

- Notebook A with IP address 192.168.0.100
- Notebook B with IP address 192.168.0.101

Notebook A can access it's htdocs or notebook B's htdocs:

[image: notebook A screen capture]

But when notebook B do the same thing, somehow it recognize notebook A's htdocs as itself:

[image: notebook B screen capture]

Both laptop installed same version of XAMPP and Google Chrome. Please Help.

Comment: [Localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) has a particular meaning: "a hostname that means this computer", normally resolving to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Thanks @Chris. I changed it to htdocs, more relevant now :)
Any clue?

Comment: In one of the screen shots, there are 10 items in the list, although in the other one there are 9. So are you sure, you are looking at the same machine from both views ?

Comment: @Alp each picture came from different machine.

Answer (score 0):

I find temporary solution for this problem by changing Start IP Address value to xxx.xxx.x.101 (via router web application), forcing all machine to reset their registered IP Address.

I don't know why, but xxx.xxx.x.100 has been taken permanently by Notebook B. Although, it's IP Address has changed to xxx.xxx.x.102, but it can still PING xxx.xxx.x.100 with <1ms like it PING itself!